# java: Auto-boxing and casting?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I'm confused with a  small problem  , see the following :

```
Double j = new Double(5); // No problem.
double j =5;//

         //But

//Here the problem:

Double j = 5;
Long k =5;      
Float g = 5.0;
```

I know the solution but I want to understand why in some situations the cast is done implicitly and in others not.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. What is the "problem"? Explain what doesn't work the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing wrong with

```
Double j = new Double(5);
```

because Java will convert `5` from an `int` to the `double` that a `Double` constructor will take.  It will also convert the `5` to a `double` for the line:

```
double j =5;
```

That is a widening primitive conversion.

There is a problem with these lines.

```
Double j = 5;
Long k =5;      
Float g = 5.0;
```

Java will not perform a widening primitive conversion (`5` to `5.0` or `5L`) and a boxing conversion (`double` to `Double` or `long` to `Long`) implicitly.  It will perform either one implicitly, but not both.  It also won't perform a narrowing primitive conversion here (`5.0` to `5.0f`).

The [JLS, Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), states:

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

It doesn't explicitly allow what those last 3 lines are attempting to do: a widening primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion.

Interestingly, Java does allow:

```
Number x = 5;  // boxing followed by widening
double y = new Integer(5);  // unboxing followed by widening
```

Comment: I doubt whether `double j=5;` will work without giving some compile-time warning/error!!! Shouldn't it be `double j=5d;`?

Comment: @shekharsuman Java allows a widening primitive conversion implicitly.  The `int` literal `5` will be converted to `5.0` implicitly.

Comment: Does anyone know why the people at Java made the decision to disallow implicit widening then boxing?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with these three assignments is that although Java has rules about widening primitive-to-primitive conversions, it has no rules for primitive-to-wrapper conversions. In other words, there is no rule that would do a conversion in addition to auto-boxing.

```
Double j = 5;  // 5 is an int literal. It can be auto-boxed only to Integer
Long k =5;     // Same here
Float g = 5.0; // 5.0 is a double literal. It can be auto-boxed only to Double
```

You can fix these by adding a proper suffix or a proper cast, like this:

```
Double j = (double)5;
Long k = 5L;      
Float g = (float)5.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Double j = new Double(5); 
double k =j;

Here unboxing is occurred. getting value from Wrapper object and assign to primitive data type(int,doulbe,float)
double k= j; is equivalent to  j.doubleValue(); return type is double

Double j = 5;

You want ti use like this, You have to mention data type,
Double a=(double)5; or Double a= Double.valueOf(5);

this is autoboxing. With out knowing data type can't java cast, otherwise you should give correct primitive data type(5.0).

Answer (score 0):

`double d = 5;` // widening

in above statement, widening is happening from primitive `int` to `double`

`Double d = new Double(5);` // wrapper class constructor used and passed with `int` type value 5, but returns wrapper class `Double` reference `d` with reference to value 5.0 as `jvm` will do `widening` on `int` type value 5 and return `double` type 5.0 which gets used by wrapper class `Double` `constructor`.

`Double d = 5.0;` // is auto boxing, it is same like `Double d = new Double(5);`

But, `Double d = 5;` // is erroneous as `int` type value 5 can not be `auto boxed` to `double` type value and referenced by `Double` type reference variable. jvm does not perform such primitive type widening for values to be referenced by wrapper class reference variable.