# Implicit conversion in wrapper class

Tags: java

I have confusion in Number Wrapper Class in Java.

These two assignments look symmetric - a `char` is assigned to `Integer`, and an `int` is assigned to `Character`. However, the first assignment

```
Integer i = 'a';
```

gives Compilation Error, while the second assignment

```
Character ch2 = 97;
```

is allowed. Why?

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to be able to convert `'a'` to an integer value?

Comment: @ericbn [Like this](http://ideone.com/jvaWzh) Essentially, OP is using `'a'` as a different way of writing `97`. This question is surprisingly tricky.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis This is not Duplicate.

Comment: You haven't explained why you don't think so, so I'll leave it as is. Here are a couple more posts that ask about the exact same issue: [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294275/java-widening-conversions) and [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332413/java-auto-boxing-and-casting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although `int i = 'a'` works fine, converting the same to `Integer` is not allowed, because it requires a boxing conversion.

Java's boxing conversion is defined only for eight cases:

- From type `boolean` to type `Boolean`
- From type `byte` to type `Byte`
- From type `short` to type `Short`
- From type `char` to type `Character`
- From type `int` to type `Integer`
- From type `long` to type `Long`
- From type `float` to type `Float`
- From type `double` to type `Double`

Since `'a'` is a `char` literal, Java does not allow conversion from `char` to `Integer`: a character literal is always of type `char`.

However, when you write

```
Character ch2 = 97;
```

Java compiler sees that 97 is in the valid range for `char` (i.e. 0..65535), so it treats `97` as `char`, not `int`, and allows the boxing conversion. Trying the same with an out-of-range constant produces an error:

```
Character ch3 = 65536; // error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Character
```

Comment: Oh those top 1% ers, always stealing our reputation ;-) ... but kudos, you figured it first ;-) ... may that blinken light be with you! If you allow the question: where is your nick name coming from?

Comment: @GhostCat It comes from [this pre-internet meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights) in a slightly different "translation": "ACHTUNG! Das machine is nicht fur gefingerpoken und mittengrabben. Ist easy schnappen der springenwerk, blowenfusen und corkenpoppen mit spitzensparken. Ist nicht fur gewerken by das dummkopfen. Das rubbernecken sightseeren keepen hands in das pockets. Relaxen und vatch das blinkenlights!"

Comment: @GhostCat Just saw the country in your profile, and I hope that you don't find this meme too offensive. By the way, the cat in your profile (British shorthair?) looks very cool.

Comment: The language thing is absolutely fine. But calling my French Chartreux (or is it Chartreuse in English) a British shorthair... Woha, that is one big no go :-)

Comment: @GhostCat Oh my, I really sorry about that! In my defense, I read these two breeds are pretty hard to tell apart by looking at a picture.

Comment: I am glad you apologized in time. Those only duells can turn out pretty nasty,so it is good that we don't need to go there. :-) beyond that, Probably the best indicator for a Chartreux cat is the eye color btw.

Answer (score 4):

The rules for boxing conversions can be found in the Java Language Spec, chapter [5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:

... followed by a list of **valid** conversions from primitive types to reference types.

The point is: in any case, a **conversion** must take place.

If you had

```
int a = '97'
```

that is fine; as that is a widening conversion (sectin 5.12 in the JLS). But that case

```
Integer i = '97'
```

isn't listed as "valid" conversion for Auto-boxing. In other words: the JLS doesn't allow for it; and this the compiler doesn't do it either.
...

Answer (score 0):

`Integer i = 'a'` just wraps `int i ='a'`.  Since `'a'` is not an `int` it throws an error.

Likewise, `Character ch2 = 97` wraps `char ch2 = 97`.  However, `97` is an valid char!  It represents the character "a".  Example:

```
System.out.println((char) 97); //Output: a
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when setting a character to an integer it's returning the ASCII code number which is a primitive int.